# npm zombie putting <head> contents inside <body>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, zombie.js

I'm using [zombie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zombie) to generate HTML snapshots for my MEAN stack single page application, following this tutorial by Angular: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html

My snapshots are being generated fine except one thing. The contents of the document `<head>` are inside the `<body>` tag and I don't know why.

In brief, I create my zombie browser like so:

```
var browser = new Zombie({
  waitFor: 3000,
  loadCSS: false,
  runScripts: true
});
```

Then I visit a page and see the html:

```
browser.visit("page-url-here").then(function(){
  console.log(browser.html());
});
```

And I get an output with this kind of structure:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
meta tags, css links, etc here.
</body>
</html>
```

The original code for those pages was done correctly with the head content inside the head tag, so why has zombie moved it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in zombie's dependency, jsdom. jsdom < v2.0 has a problem with some html capabilities. The jsdom version is updated in zombie version 3.0.1-0. Use npm to update zombie to 3.0.1-0 or higher.

`npm install zombie@3.0.11.0` for current newest version.

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/847